# How to have dependencies that result from another target in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I've tweak "a bit" Make so I can use it as a "kind of" cli for some tasks.

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-variables
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory

SHELL := /bin/bash

.ONESHELL:

.PHONY: project_list
project_list: all_projects_info.json
    echo "Filtering project list with:" >&2
    echo "  PROJECT_FILTER: $(PROJECT_FILTER)" >&2
    jq -r -S '.[] | select(
        (.projectId | test("$(PROJECT_FILTER)"))
        )  | .projectId' $^ > $@

.PHONY: get_storage_info
get_storage_info: project_list
    PROJECT_LIST=$$(cat $<)
    $(MAKE) -f $(MKFILE) -j storage_info.json PROJECT_LIST="$$PROJECT_LIST"




all_projects_info.json:
    curl -X GET https://toto/get_all_my_projects_info >$@


# here it's PHONY because we want to always rebuild it
.PHONY: storage_info.json
storage_info.json: $(STORAGE_INFO_JSON_FILES) 
    jq -s -S '[.[]?.items?[]?]' $(STORAGE_INFO_JSON_FILES) > $@


storage_info/:
    mkdir -p $@

STORAGE_INFO_JSON_FILES=$(foreach project_name,$(PROJECT_LIST),storage_info/$(project_name).json)

$(STORAGE_INFO_JSON_FILES): storage_info/%.json: | storage_info/
    curl \
        -X GET \
        "https://storage_api/list_s3?project=$*" \
        2> /dev/null > $@
```

As you can see here, I've got 2 "command":

- `project_list` witch list all project I can access too,
- `get_storage_info` witch list all bucket in projects.

The trick here is because I've got a lot of projects and buckets, I may want to filter like this:
`make get_storage_info PROJECT="foo"`
And it will print **ONLY** bucket in project with `foo` in their name.

It's quit handy and fast (only the first time it may be slow, the time to get all informations).

What is bothering me, I've not found a better way than to call a sub make command (with the exact list of project to take into account).

Is it possible to express dynamic dependencies of a target ?
But something that can result from another target ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can (and do) specify dependencies via `make` variables, and these can take different values on different runs based on a variety of factors.  Is that consistent with what you mean by "express dynamic dependencies of a target"?  If not, then please clarify what you *do* mean.

Comment: Note: declaring a genuine target phony in order to force it to be rebuilt every time is counterintuitive, and a desire to do it suggests that `make` is the wrong tool for your job (which it definitely is).  But if you continue along these lines, then I would find it clearer to force a genuine target always to be rebuilt by making it *depend* on a phony target, rather than by making it *be* one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In fact, this Makefile is a small part of a "real" one, and the storage_info.json is in fact in a "cache folder" and not in the current folder.
But I did not wanted to pollute this post too much.

Comment: Ok. So, you can (and do) specify dependencies via `make` variables, and these can take different values on different runs based on a variety of factors. Is that consistent with what you mean by "express dynamic dependencies of a target"? If not, then please clarify what you do mean.

Comment: In any case, I think `make` is the wrong tool for your job.  You're going to a lot of trouble to get it to work much like a shell script, and I think it would probably be cleaner and more natural to go all the way and just write the script you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with invoking a submake.  That's IMO the best way to do it, *especially* if you want to add `-j` to it.

It's not really possible to get rid of this easily.  It's not the fact that you want to express a dynamic dependency: that can be done.  The problem is you want the list of dependencies to be extracted from the *results* of running another rule.  But that's not how make works: make always starts with the final target and works its way backwards.  So, by the time you get around to building the prerequisite file, the target that depended on it has already been processed (not its recipe of course, but all the prerequisites).

Comment: I understand that what I am doing is not the way make was build for.

But I would like to have only one process so I hope it would be easier to read, and feel more "make natural".

Comment: I'll say it slightly differently then: the makefile code you need to write to make this work without recursion, would be very complicated and very hard to read... way, way more than just using recursion.  I am not sure why recursion would not be "make natural"; in fact many makefiles contain at least some recursion.

Comment: Ok thanks !
Clearer this way indeed ;)